# bundle.js slow loading

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, load, bundle

bundle.js (2.4 Mb) loading take 40 sec - 1.5 min: [image: screenshot here]

This is my `webpack.config.js` :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
 entry: {
        "App":__dirname + '/js/App.jsx'
},
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      loader: 'babel-loader?cashezdirectory'
    },
   // { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
  ]
},
externals: {
react: 'React',
jquery: 'jQuery'}
};
module.exports = config;
```

Is the any way to make loading faster?

Comment: Regardless what optimization one uses - a 2.4 MB file should not take 1.5 minutes to load... Are there any errors in the console? Memory spikes in the dev tools? Also - what browser? I had issues with Firefox and Sourcemaps in the past - which have been resolved.

Comment: Part of the problem was a large distance to the server and partly not enough optimization. Although the bottom answer is belated but it is similar to the one I used earlier. I also decided to divide into smaller parts and download them as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration that you are using for webpack seems to be a development version. Try using a production configuration which usually provides extra optimisations like uglification and extract CSS plugin.

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true
    })
],
```

This should reduce the bundle size considerably(at least half).

You should also check your server configuration for further optimisations like gzipping which will reduce the download size by ~5 times.

Comment: 2.4mb is not that big to be loaded instantly from local dev server, is it?

Comment: For local dev server, definitely not a big deal at all. But for production, definitely an issue